# How can I find my building in a superflat world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I made a superflat world and typed `/tp ~ ~ ~-10000` or something similar a few times to have a separate area to build a house on, but i accidentally died and lost my house. What can I do to find it?

I have McEdit if that helps.

Comment: What exactly is the issue...

Comment: Do you know your house's location in MCEdit (maybe zoom out a lot)? If yes, get the coords from there and /tppos yourself.

Answer (score 5):

If you had any entities in your building that do not spawn naturally in the superflat, eg. Villagers, cats, dogs, horses,  item frames, dropped items ("Item") etc., you can try to teleport to them:

```
/tp @p @e[type=EntityName]
```

Don't forget to write the type of entity with a capital letter at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming no-one traveled in a different direction, you can look at the region files to find the one furthest away from spawn. Your building is likely in that 512x512 area.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to use a compass to lead you back to your original spawnpoint (if that is where you want to get back to). Follow the red line in the compass until you see your build in or just wait until the lines turns over and faces the other way. I'm sure there is other ways but this is the simplest.

Comment: The OP said they did the command to get ***away*** from their spawn, they want to find their build, and it seems they do not remember the actual command, so they could not repeat it